# Ruby libxml parsing and inserting to database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, xml, parsing, libxml2

I am currently trying to read from an xml file which records the jobs on a PBS. I have succesfullly managed to parse the code, but am unable to insert the objtects into my database, i receive this error:

"You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.delete"

This is my Model:

```
require 'xml/libxml'

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  JOB_DIR = File.join('data', 'jobs')

  attr_reader :jobid, :user, :group, :jobname, :queue, :ctime
  attr_reader :qtime, :etime, :start, :owner

  def initialize(jobid, user, group, jobname, queue, ctime, qtime, etime, start, owner)
    @jobid, @user, @group, @jobname, @queue = jobid, user, group, jobname, queue
    @ctime, @qtime, @etime, @start, @owner = ctime, qtime, etime, start, owner
  end

  def self.find_all()
    jobs = []
    input_file = "#{JOB_DIR}/1.xml"
    doc = XML::Document.file(input_file) 
    doc.find('//execution_record').each do |node| 
      jobs << Job.new(
        node.find('jobid').to_a.first.content,
        node.find('user').to_a.first.content,
        node.find('group').to_a.first.content,
        node.find('jobname').to_a.first.content,
        node.find('queue').to_a.first.content,
        node.find('ctime').to_a.first.content,
        node.find('qtime').to_a.first.content,
        node.find('etime').to_a.first.content,
        node.find('start').to_a.first.content,
        node.find('owner').to_a.first.content

      )
    end
    jobs
  end
end
```

An my Model Controller:

```
class JobController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @jobs = Job.find_all()
  end

  def create
    @jobs = Job.find_all()
    for job in @jobs
      job.save
    end
  end

end
```

I would appreciate any help...Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on the causes of the error message you're seeing because I can't see anywhere that you're trying to invoke a `delete` method, however this does seem like a slightly confused use of ActiveRecord.

If you have a `jobs` database table with fields `jobid`, `user`, `group`, `jobname` etc. then ActiveRecord will create accessor methods for these and you should not be using `attr_reader` or overriding `initialize`. You should also not be setting values value instance variables (`@jobid` etc.) If you *don't* have such fields on your table then there is nothing in your current code to map the values from the XML the database fields.

Your `def self.find_all` method should probably be along the lines of:

```
def self.build_from_xml
  jobs = []
  input_file = "#{JOB_DIR}/1.xml"
  doc = XML::Document.file(input_file) 
  doc.find('//execution_record').each do |node| 
    jobs << Job.new(
      :jobid => node.find('jobid').to_a.first.content,
      :user => node.find('user').to_a.first.content,
  ...
```

Rails used to have a method of its own `find_all` to retrieve all existing records from the database so your method name is probably a bit misleading. Rails tends to use the *build* verb to mean *create a new model object but don't save it yet* so that's why I've gone with a name like `build_from_xml`.

Comment: @jalagrange I know you have accepted the answer but I don't feel I've helped you that much - feel free to post any follow up questions when you get a bit further.